# How parse line of NAT log and make a specific CSV output

Tags: parsing, awk, sed, cut

I have a NAT device that makes NAT logs like this:

```
Dec 13 18:12:59 172.16.1.1 "LSN_DELETE""192.168.100.1%101:11921""TCP""100.100.100.100%101:11921""104.111.224.226:80""1481639868477""327573"
```

I want to make a csv file by converting each line of this file to:

```
192.168.100.1,11921,TCP,100.100.100.100,11921,104.111.224.226,80,1481639868477,327573
```

I know that I can read the file line by line and convert it using cut command but reading file line by line is very slow and the file is very huge (5 million lines). I want to convert it by awk or sed that are more fast. could someone please help me to do that?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? You are supposed to show specific issue with your code. Otherwise, the question looks like an assignment.

Comment: Unless you want a solution that only works for that one specific line of input, also post a FEW lines of concise, testable sample input and expected output that can be used to prove a given script satisfies all your requirements. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk, a partial solution (you'll have to add fields in the order you like):

```
gawk -F '[^.[:digit:][:alpha:]]*' -v OFS=, '{print $9,$15,$12}' file
```

That is, assuming the log is in the file named `file`:

- It breaks each line up using the field separator (-F), where is
  assumes (and this may not be 100% depending on your data) that a
  field any number of contiguous periods, digits, and alpha characters.
- The output field separator (OFS) is set to comma
- The chosen fields are printed, rearranged.

No guarantees that this will be faster than what you were doing before.

Comment: There is nothing gawk-specific about that script.

Comment: It works fine. Just one more question.I tried to print a math on $18 and $19 and print the output, but it prints the exponential output, like this  '{print (($18+$19)/1000) }'  => 1.48166e+12. How should I print it rounded and non-exponential? Like this 1481661496

Comment: I found the answer: {print int(($18+$19)/1000)}. Thanks.